# Environment variable in cmd created with System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a simple program "runelevated.exe" in c# which create a process with "runas" verb.

I use this program to run executables files with elevation privilege (UAC) in command line (I give the path of the "exe" file in parameter).

It works well, but today I saw that if I run a batch file with my "runelevated" program, all variables created within my batch file don't work !

For example, if i run `runelevated.exe mybatch.bat` it will output only `my name is`

mybatch.bat contents:

```
    SET my=buchu
    echo my name is %my%
```

I tried with differents combinations in the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` used to start the process (`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute, ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile`) without sucess.
Maybe with `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` can help, but I don't really understand its use

Here is the runElevated source:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        if(args.Length>0) {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo=new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(args[0]);
            if(args.Length>1) {
                startInfo.Arguments=string.Join(" ", args, 1, args.Length-1);
            }
            startInfo.Verb="runas";
            //startInfo.UseShellExecute=true;
            //startInfo.LoadUserProfile=true;

            try {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch(Exception exception) {
                Console.WriteLine("error while launching:\n" + exception.Message);
            }
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: runElevated [programPath] [arguments ...]");
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the process?

Comment: have you tried to use setx instead  of set in your bat files

Comment: hm, will that really help..? : [_Because SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry, edits will only take effect when a new command window is opened - they do not affect the current CMD or PowerShell session._](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Comment: i don't try with SETX because i don't want variables stay alive after the process run

Comment: Are you sure it does work when run without that runelevated.exe?

Comment: @olivier sow Do you need to manually elevate the C# program for the process to run? If so, I have successfully use a vbscript to elevate and manage processes.

Comment: Trying `ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile` suggests u were looking to have RunAs user's environment vars (saved in the registry) available to the .BAT file. However the problem you describe in your two line .BAT script is not related to whether profile environment vars are set. Simply setting a var in the batch file isn't working. So you need to debug that. 1) What happens if u right click the .BAT and select RunAs? 2) Try putting a bare `SET` command before and after `SET my=buchu`. Does `my` show up in output from second `SET`? 3) What happens if u change value of an existing (not new) var?

Comment: Did you try `runelevated.exe cmd.exe mybatch.bat`?